# FFT-Convolution. Convolve 4D Image with 4D Filter

Tags: python, numpy, fft, convolution

I want to create CNN network on Python with only in plain NumPy. For optimizing the time of convolution(actually correlation) in network, I wanna try to use FFT-based Convolution.
Data that needs to be convoluted(correlated) is 4D Image tensor with shape
`[batch_size, width, height, channels]` and 4D Filter tensor
`[filter_width, filter_height, in_channel, out_channel]`.
I read a lot of articles about FFT-based convolution, but they aren't doing in my way.
Thus, I need in your help.